# Ubuntu Install Not Showing Up In Boot Options XPS 9575

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, uefi, dell-xps

XPS 9575 running windows 10, after disabling secure boot, switching to AHCI SATA operation, I had to enable legacy roms but it said external devices only so it can boot the Ubuntu live USB at all. After allocating partitions in Ubuntu install wizard & selecting the same partition as "/" for which to install GRUB & what seems like a successful install, there is no boot option present for this Ubuntu install only Windows boot manager. Booting to Ubuntu live, Gparted shows that the partitions created in the wizard are present & have some space used too.

My hypotheses is that it booted the Ubuntu live disk in Legacy mode so it installed it in legacy mode which is not supported for internal storage devices. Somehow it doesn't see the Ubuntu USB Live disk in UEFI mode, I can confirm that my other XPS (7590) successfully installed Ubuntu from the same Live Disk and works fine.

Comment: UEFI boot menu should offer two boot modes for USB flash drive or DVD, if Secure Boot is off. You may have to turn on USB settings to allow USB boot. Many Dell often need UEFI update & if SSD, firmware update. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I have the USB boot enabled, also Thunderbolt boot and Thunderbolt preboot modules enabled as it only has USB-C ports and I thought to enable all just in case. The USB drive doesn't show up in the One Time Boot Options menu in without enabling "Legacy option roms for external devices" which is the only legacy mode supported. I think since the Live USB booted in Legacy then it installed in Legacy too which is not supported on internal devices. Should I try to connect the SSD externally & try to boot from it? And then change to UEFI?

Comment: Not seen users booting from USB-C. Some with USB3 have had to use a USB2 port. But that totally depends on UEFI vendor & and often some UEFI settings. The main differences with BIOS/MBR & UEFI/gpt is the partitioning & version of grub. The Ubuntu / is the same except for a few settings that the reinstall of grub changed. So partition in advance with gpt, make sure you have an ESP. BIOS install ot gpt will create a 1MB bios_grub, but with UEFI that will not be used. Similar Dell? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2408749 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2408585

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific use case, save yourself the pain of dual-booting Ubuntu and Win 10. Simply install Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL) and you're good to go.